# Data Wrangling for Modeling in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, modeling

I have a data set (original version, `# A tibble: 33,478 x 12`) of the form similar to the attached picture, and partial data:

[image]

`dput(head(canals2, n=10))`

```
 structure(list(Site = c(1, 2, 4, 11, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16), 
    `Sample Date` = c("2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", 
    "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", 
    "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004"), `Analysis code` = c("NH3", "NH3", 
    "NH3", "Chl a", "Chl a", "Chl a", "NH3", "Chl a", "NH3", 
    "NH3"), Analysis = c("Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Ammonia-Nitrogen", 
    "Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", 
    "Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Chlorophyll a", "Ammonia-Nitrogen", 
    "Ammonia-Nitrogen"), Result = c(0.068, 0.07, 0.014, 1.31, 
    1.39, 1.95, 0.247, 1.46, 0.113, 0.17), Units = c("mg/L", 
    "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/m3", "mg/m3", "mg/m3", "mg/L", "mg/m3", 
    "mg/L", "mg/L")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to try to predict, for instance, "Chlorophyll a" from "Ammonia-Nitrogen" using a linear model (say, using the `lm()` function). `lm()` takes column names as inputs for 'formula', yet this dataset was generated very differently. I should be using the values in the `Results` column for each analysis, but I can't seem to find a good way of organizing my data as such.

So far, I tried splitting the data by analysis, with the intention of creating a new dataframe for each analysis, then replacing the `Result` with the name of the analysis selected in that dataframe.  Here is the function I used (ran it on the main data set, which is why it contains more analysis names):

`analysis_list = unique(canals$Analysis)`

`> analysis_list`

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L1Fu.png) "Ammonia-Nitrogen"        "Chlorophyll a"           "Fecal Coliform"
[4] "Specific Conductance"    "Copper"                  "Dissolved Oxygen"
[7] "E Coli"                  "Enterococci"             "Nitrite + Nitrate"
[10] "Ortho-Phosphate"         "pH"                      "Salinity"
[13] "Temperature"             "Total Kjeldahl Nitrogen" "Total Nitrogen"
[16] "Total Phosphorus"        "Turbidity"

```
split_analyses <- function()
  canals_byAnalysis <- vector(mode = "list", length = 0)
  for (i in 1:17) {
    analysis <- analysis_list[i]
    updated_analysis <- canals %>% 
                    subset(Analysis == analysis, 
                    select = -c(`Analysis code`))
    canals_byAnalysis[[i]] <- updated_analysis
  }

split_analyses()
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work as expected, and I had many issues merging the tables I created. I tried other ways as well, but I am getting nowhere. Is anyone willing to offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then it sounds like you're trying to restructure your data to get it into the proper form for modelling purposes. I think using `pivot_wider` (from `tidyr`) will get you what you want. Here's what I did:

First, here's your data as a dataframe:

```
Site <- c(1, 2, 4, 11, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16)
Sample_Date <- c("2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", 
"2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004", "2/11/2004")
Analysis_code <- c("NH3", "NH3", "NH3", "Chl a", "Chl a", "Chl a", "NH3", "Chl 
a", "NH3", "NH3")
Analysis <- c("Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Ammonia-Nitrogen", 
"Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Chlorophyll a", "Ammonia-Nitrogen", 
"Chlorophyll a", "Ammonia-Nitrogen", "Ammonia-Nitrogen")
Results <- c(0.068, 0.07, 0.014, 1.31, 1.39, 1.95, 0.247, 1.46, 0.113, 0.17)
Units <- c("mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/L", "mg/m3", "mg/m3", "mg/m3", "mg/L", "mg/m3", 
"mg/L", "mg/L")

   Site Sample_Date Analysis_code         Analysis Results Units
1     1   2/11/2004           NH3 Ammonia-Nitrogen   0.068  mg/L
2     2   2/11/2004           NH3 Ammonia-Nitrogen   0.070  mg/L
3     4   2/11/2004           NH3 Ammonia-Nitrogen   0.014  mg/L
4    11   2/11/2004         Chl a    Chlorophyll a   1.310 mg/m3
5    10   2/11/2004         Chl a    Chlorophyll a   1.390 mg/m3
```

Next, we'll apply `pivot_wider` to spread the `Analysis` variable. This will leave you with a column for each of the `Analysis` types you have, along with their respective `Results` value.

```
#spread the analysis variable
new_df <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Analysis", values_from = "Results")

    Site Sample_Date Analysis_code Units `Ammonia-Nitrogen` `Chlorophyll a`
   <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <chr>              <dbl>           <dbl>
 1     1 2/11/2004   NH3           mg/L               0.068           NA   
 2     2 2/11/2004   NH3           mg/L               0.07            NA   
 3     4 2/11/2004   NH3           mg/L               0.014           NA   
 4    11 2/11/2004   Chl a         mg/m3             NA                1.31
 5    10 2/11/2004   Chl a         mg/m3             NA                1.39
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution worked wonderfully here, however when trying to implement it on the full dataset, the spread variables (each "Analysis") became a <list> instead of a numeric data type (<dbl>, as in your dataframe above). This caused errors with the lm() function. Could it be b/c of the NAs generated by spreading the Analysis variable?

Comment: Try converting back to numeric using `as.numeric`. I'm assuming you're trying to build individual models for each of your `Analysis` types - e.g., one Ammonia-Nitrogen model, one for Chlorophyll a, etc. If this is the case, you could build each model purely on the records where that model's response variable (e.g., Ammonia-Nitrogen) is not NULL.

The `lm` function does have some built-in functionality on dealing with NA's, however, I believe it mostly applies to the model's explanatory variables. See `na.action` in https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm

Comment: When using `as.numeric` I get the error `'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`, and when I use `na.action = na.omit` with the `lm()` function, I get the error `'invalid type (list) for variable <varname>'`.

Comment: ... And yes, I would like to build models for some of the individual analyses, then multiple linear regression models in an attempt to predict Chlorophyll a from relevant analyses.

Comment: Hmm, try using the `unlist()` function to convert the list into a vector and then give that a try with `as.numeric`. Another way could be using `lapply` to apply the `as.numeric` function to each element of your list.

Comment: `lapply()` with `as.numeric` gave me the error `'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`. `unlist()` worked well however, it pulls the observations from the dataframe out into a vector, so I loose the key identifier for these results, the `Site`.